# sed replace with text in file that has & characters

Tags: sed

I am trying a sed replacement from a text file and whats in the text file has a & character in different parts of whats in the text file so it just appends it.  I want to replace and not append.  I am doing this with multiple vars and the & is in different spots on each var and sometimes back to back & characters inthe middle of the string.

```
echo $myvar > temp.txt
sed -i "s/orignaltxt/$(cat temp.txt)/" file.yaml
```

Comment: `s/originaltxt/cat temp.txt/e` will work to do exactly what you want here.  `s///e` takes whatever is on the replacement side and calls the shell to obtain the replacement string, and it can include ampersand.  `/originaltext/r temp.txt` is similar but will append rather than replace.